# The system of exponential equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

How do you solve:
$$\begin{cases}
x\cdot2^{x-y}+3y\cdot2^{2x+y-1}=1 \hspace{0.1cm},\\ x\cdot2^{2x+y+1}+3y\cdot8^{x+y}=1\\
\end{cases}$$
I subtracted the equations, factorized by grouping, and got two terms equal zero. When I tried to use one of the terms, by expressing one variable through another and put it back in the first equation, it became complicated, so I gave up.

Result is: $ (x=1, \hspace{0.1cm}y=-1) $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By dividing the second equation by $2^{x+2y+1}$ we get
$$\begin{cases}
x\cdot2^{x-y}+3y\cdot2^{2x+y-1}=1 \\
x\cdot2^{x-y}+3y\cdot2^{2x+y-1}=2^{-(x+2y+1)}
\end{cases}$$
which implies that $x=-2y-1$. Hence from the first equation we get
$$-(2y+1)\cdot2^{-3y-1}+3y\cdot2^{-3y-3}=1$$
that is
$$f(y):=5y+4+8\cdot 2^{3y}=0$$
Now note that $f$ is a strictly increasing function (it is the sum of the strictly increasing functions $g_1(y)=5y+4$ and $g_2(y)=8\cdot 2^{3y}$). Therefore $f$ is injective and $f(-1)=0$ implies that $y=-1$ is the only zero of $f$. Finally $x=-2y-1=1$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's a typo in the equation just before the definition of $f$.  Shouldn't the exponent in the last term be $-3y-3$ instead of $-3y-5?$

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, you are right! Thank you very much.

Comment: in which cases function would have more than one zeros?

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic  I have no general statement to suggest. $f$ has to be NOT injective for sure. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function

Answer (score 0):

We obtain $$x(2^{x-y}-2^{2x+y+1})+3y(2^{2x+y-1}-2^{3x+3y})=0$$ or
$$x2^{x-y}(1-2^{x+2y+1})+3y(1-2^{x+2y+1})=0,$$ which gives
$$x2^{x-y}+3y=0$$ or
$$x+2y+1=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: that is exactly what I got, what's next?